# Android menu icon not display in Action Bar

Tags: android, android-menu

This is my menu item code,

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/budget_create" android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:icon="@drawable/add"
           android::showAsAction="ifRoom"   
           android:title="New Monthly Budget"

         ></item>
   </menu>
```

This is my java code,

```
    @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.budget_create_menu, menu);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.budget_create:

        Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),Budget_Monthly_details.class);

          startActivity(i);
          getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_slide_in_top, R.anim.abc_slide_out_top);

        break;
 }
```

**Edited**

**After onMenuOpened() code added I get images like this.**

I want icon in Action Bar.

[image]

Comment: what theme you are using for your activity

Comment: Theme.AppCompat.Light

Comment: you have to add dpi base image then set it to icon attribute... then works...

Comment: @NAP I got answer from below code.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: see your profile.your down votes=51. total votes=93

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code to your `Activity` where you are inflating your menu.. That piece of code worked for me.. hope it works for you too..

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    if (featureId == Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR && menu != null) {
        if (menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder")) {
            try {
                Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                        "setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
                m.setAccessible(true);
                m.invoke(menu, true);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onMenuOpened", e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}
```

**Note :** This method is only applicable for `Activity` only.. `Fragments` doesn't support `onMenuOpened()` method.

EDITED :

**If you want ICON visible in Actionbar (Outside of Overflow Menu)..**

try following option..

```
       yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

**e.g.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:icon="@drawable/add"
        android:title="My Monthly Budget"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always"  />

</menu>
```

Comment: Get return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu); undefined in fragment error

Comment: i mentioned ACTIVITY.. try to post it in your activity which holds this fragment..

Comment: but if you write it in Activity.. it will affect for fragments too... bcoz fragments call activities MENU while adding new items.. try to add it in ACTIVITY and run your program.

Comment: After adding android:showAsAction="always",still get same view.help me.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Menu layout file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:icon="@drawable/add"
        android:title="My Monthly Budget"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```